# How to get What version of Microsoft Exchange Server was used for a given Exchange database(EDB file only)?

Tags: database, exchange-server, exchange-server-2013, edb, exchange-server-2016

I have a Microsoft exchange database file(.edb file). I don't remember what version of microsoft exchange server was used in order to create the database file. Need help.

Comment: `eseutil -mh foo.edb`. Look for the engine version and paste it. Something like 0x620,f. I don't have the table of engine version-to-Exchange version though.

Comment: I can use eseutil only if i have exchange server in the system. Is there any independent solution? @MartinChisholm

Comment: Technically you can copy `eseutil.exe`/`ese.dll` from an Exchange server and run them elsewhere. Whether that's permitted by the EULA I do not know.
How are your C# skills? You can use managedesent.codeplex.com and `Api.JetGetDatabaseFileInfo`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn292159(v=exchg.10).aspx Look for `dbinfomisc.ulVersion` and `dbinfomisc.ulUpdate` to get the same information as `eseutil` returns. In general you shouldn't ever use ManagedEsent to write to an Exchange database (subtle differences between ese.dll and esent.dll), but doing ReadOnly access is safe.